# Validating and Parsing Forsythe-Edwards Notation in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm seeking to get some more practice in rust by writing a chess engine.

One of the first parts of this, as it will make testing all further parts easier, is the ability to validate and parse [Forsythe-Edwards Notation](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation) state descriptions.

I've got something that seems to work, however, I'm certain how I'm doing it is neither optimal, nor idiomatic rust. So, having come from a largely C# background, I'm looking for guidance as to how I can make this more idiomatic.

Here's my implementation:

```rs
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Fen {
    pub piece_placement: String,
    pub active_colour: String,
    pub castling_ability: String,
    pub en_passant_target: String,
    pub halfmove_clock: String,
    pub fullmove_clock: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum FenValidationError {
    InvalidCodeInRank(String, Vec<char>),
    IncorrectRankSize(String, u8),
    InvalidActiveColour(String),
    InvalidCastlingCode(String),
    InvalidEnPassantTarget(String),
    InvalidHalfMoveClock(String),
    InvalidFullMoveClock(String),
    InvalidNumberOfFenComponents(String, u8),
}

impl TryFrom<&str> for Fen {
    type Error = FenValidationError;

    fn try_from(value: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let parts: Vec<&str> = value.split(' ').collect();

        if parts.len() != 6 {
            return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidNumberOfFenComponents(value.to_string(), parts.len() as u8))
        }

        match Fen::validate_piece_placement_substring(parts[0])
            .and_then(|_| Fen::validate_active_colour(parts[1]))
            .and_then(|_| Fen::validate_castling_ability(parts[2]))
            .and_then(|_| Fen::validate_en_passant(parts[3]))
            .and_then(|_| Fen::validate_half_move_clock(parts[4]))
            .and_then(|_| Fen::validate_full_move_clock(parts[5])) {
            Ok(()) => Ok(Fen {
                piece_placement: parts[0].to_string(),
                active_colour: parts[1].to_string(),
                castling_ability: parts[2].to_string(),
                en_passant_target: parts[3].to_string(),
                halfmove_clock: parts[4].to_string(),
                fullmove_clock: parts[5].to_string(),
            }),
            Err(e) => Err(e)
        }
    }
}

impl ToString for Fen {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        format!("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}",self.piece_placement, self.active_colour, self.castling_ability, self.en_passant_target, self.halfmove_clock, self.fullmove_clock)
    }
}

use regex::Regex;
impl Fen {
    fn validate_piece_placement_substring(placement: &str) -> Result<(), FenValidationError> {
        const ALLOWED_CODES: &'static str = "KQRBNPkqrbnp12345678";

        let ranks: Vec<&str> = placement.split('/').collect();

        for rank in ranks {
            let invalid_chars: Vec<char> = rank.chars().filter(|&c| !ALLOWED_CODES.contains(c)).collect();
            if invalid_chars.len() != 0 {
                return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCodeInRank(rank.to_string(), invalid_chars));
            }

            let mut acc: u8 = 0;
            for code in rank.chars() {
                acc += match code {
                    '2' => 2,
                    '3' => 3,
                    '4' => 4,
                    '5' => 5,
                    '6' => 6,
                    '7' => 7,
                    '8' => 8,
                    _ => 1
                };
            }

            if acc != 8 {
                return Err(FenValidationError::IncorrectRankSize(rank.to_string(), acc));
            }
        }
        return Ok(());
    }

    fn validate_active_colour(colour: &str) -> Result<(), FenValidationError> {
        match colour {
            "w" | "b"  => Ok(()),
            _ => Err(FenValidationError::InvalidActiveColour(colour.to_string()))
        }
    }

    fn validate_castling_ability(castling: &str) -> Result<(), FenValidationError> {

        struct CodesFound {
            white_ks: bool,
            black_ks: bool,
            white_qs: bool,
            black_qs: bool
        }

        if castling == "-" {
            return Ok(());
        }

        let mut found = CodesFound {
            white_ks: false,
            black_ks: false,
            white_qs: false,
            black_qs: false,
        };

        for code in castling.chars() {
            match code {
                'k' => {
                    if found.black_ks {
                        return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCastlingCode(castling.to_string()));
                    }
                    found.black_ks = true;
                },
                'K' => {
                    if found.white_ks {
                        return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCastlingCode(castling.to_string()));
                    }
                    found.white_ks = true;
                },
                'q' => {
                    if found.black_qs {
                        return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCastlingCode(castling.to_string()));
                    }
                    found.black_qs = true;
                }
                'Q' => {
                    if found.white_qs {
                        return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCastlingCode(castling.to_string()));
                    }
                    found.white_qs = true;
                }
                _ => return Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCastlingCode(castling.to_string()))
            };

        }

        return Ok(())
    }

    fn validate_en_passant(en_passant: &str) -> Result<(), FenValidationError> {
        let en_passant_regex: Regex = Regex::new(r"^[a-h][1-8]$").unwrap();

        if en_passant == "-" || en_passant_regex.is_match(en_passant) {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidEnPassantTarget(en_passant.to_string()))
        }
    }

    fn validate_half_move_clock(hmc: &str) -> Result<(), FenValidationError> {
        match hmc.parse::<u16>() {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(_) => Err(FenValidationError::InvalidHalfMoveClock(hmc.to_string()))
        }
    }

    fn validate_full_move_clock(fmc: &str) -> Result<(), FenValidationError> {
        match fmc.parse::<u16>() {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(_) => Err(FenValidationError::InvalidFullMoveClock(fmc.to_string()))
        }
    }
}
```

Of particular concern to is the best way to handle validation errors and results. It seems like I should be able to just do something that lets me:

- Call a method that returns a result.
- If it's an error, return that error up the stack
- Otherwise carry on with the internal value.

However, I can't see a way of doing this that isn't just constantly matching, but I can't believe there's no tidier way to do this. It might well be possible with something similar to `.and_then()`.

It's also worth noting I've made the deliberate choice to keep the properties in the parsed struct as strings, these will be further parsed in another module because, fundamentally, FEN is just a string in a very particular format.

If it's of interest, I also have these test cases:

````rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test_case::test_case;
    use shoulds::*;
    use crate::notation::fen::{Fen, FenValidationError};

    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w w w w w w w w w w"; "for too many parts")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR"; "for not enough parts")]
    fn it_returns_error(raw_fen: &str) {
        let result = Fen::try_from(raw_fen);
        result.should_be_error();
    }

    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR", "w", "KQkq", "-", "0", "1"; "for initial position")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR", "b", "KQkq", "e3", "0", "1"; "for 1.e4")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR", "b", "KQkq", "c6", "0", "2"; "for 1.e4 c5")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R", "b", "KQkq", "-", "1", "2"; "for 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3")]
    fn it_returns_parsed_result(piece_placement: &str, active_colour: &str, castling_ability: &str, en_passant_target: &str, halfmove_clock: &str, fullmove_clock: &str) {
        let raw = format!("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", piece_placement, active_colour, castling_ability, en_passant_target, halfmove_clock, fullmove_clock);

        let res = Fen::try_from(&*raw);
        res.should_be_ok();

        let received_parsed = res.unwrap();

        received_parsed.piece_placement.should_be(piece_placement.to_string());
        received_parsed.active_colour.should_be(active_colour.to_string());
        received_parsed.castling_ability.should_be(castling_ability.to_string());
        received_parsed.en_passant_target.should_be(en_passant_target.to_string());
        received_parsed.halfmove_clock.should_be(halfmove_clock.to_string());
        received_parsed.fullmove_clock.should_be(fullmove_clock.to_string());
    }

    #[test]
    fn it_returns_invalid_hmc_for_letters() {
        let res = Fen::validate_half_move_clock("asff123");
        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidHalfMoveClock(_)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn it_returns_valid_hmc_for_numbers() {
        for i in 0..11898 {
            Fen::validate_half_move_clock(&i.to_string()).should_be_ok();
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn it_returns_invalid_fmc_for_letters() {
        let res = Fen::validate_full_move_clock("asff123");
        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidFullMoveClock(_)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn it_returns_valid_fmc_for_numbers() {
        for i in 0..5949 {
            Fen::validate_half_move_clock(&i.to_string()).should_be_ok();
        }
    }

    #[test_case("q1"; "for too large rank")]
    #[test_case("a9"; "for too large file")]
    #[test_case("a0"; "for too small file")]
    #[test_case("adgfadfha"; "for mess")]
    fn it_returns_invalid_en_passant(en_passant_substring: &str) {
        let res = Fen::validate_en_passant(en_passant_substring);
        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidEnPassantTarget(_)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }


    #[test]
    fn it_returns_valid_en_passant_target_for_all_valid_squares() {
        let rank_codes = "abcdefgh";
        let file_codes = "12345678";

        for rank in rank_codes.chars() {
            for file in file_codes.chars() {

                let target = rank.to_string() + &file.to_string();
                Fen::validate_en_passant(&target).should_be_ok();
            }
        }
    }


    #[test_case("kk"; "for duplicate bk")]
    #[test_case("KK"; "for duplicate WK")]
    #[test_case("qq"; "for duplicate bq")]
    #[test_case("QQ"; "for duplicate WQ")]
    #[test_case("a"; "for invalid char")]
    #[test_case("kqkq"; "masked dupe")]
    fn it_returns_invalid_castling_ability(castling_substring: &str) {
        let res = Fen::validate_castling_ability(castling_substring);
        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCastlingCode(_)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }

    #[test_case("k"; "for k")]
    #[test_case("kK"; "for kK")]
    #[test_case("kKq"; "for kKq")]
    #[test_case("kKqQ"; "for kKqQ")]
    #[test_case("q"; "for q")]
    #[test_case("qQ"; "for qQ")]
    #[test_case("qQk"; "for qQk")]
    #[test_case("qQkK"; "for qQkK")]
    #[test_case("kq"; "for kq")]
    #[test_case("kqQK"; "for kqQk")]
    #[test_case("-"; "for none")]
    fn it_returns_castling_ability_is_valid(castling_substring: &str) {
        Fen::validate_castling_ability(castling_substring).should_be_ok();
    }

    #[test_case("a"; "for a")]
    #[test_case("c"; "for b")]
    #[test_case("xyzasdf"; "for mess")]
    fn it_returns_invalid_active_colour(colour_substring: &str) {
        let res = Fen::validate_active_colour(colour_substring);
        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidActiveColour(_)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }

    #[test_case("w"; "for w")]
    #[test_case("b"; "for b")]
    fn it_returns_active_colour_is_valid(colour_substring: &str) {
        Fen::validate_active_colour(colour_substring).should_be_ok();
    }

    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR"; "for initial position")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR"; "for position after 1.e4")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR"; "for position then after 1...c5")]
    #[test_case("rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R"; "for position then after 2.Nf3")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/8/8/8/8/8"; "for empty board")]
    #[test_case("1p2pp2/2N3Kk/8/8/rRrR4/6pp/7k/8"; "for random semantically valid mishmash")]
    fn it_returns_placement_is_valid(placement_substring: &str) {
        Fen::validate_piece_placement_substring(placement_substring).should_be_ok();
    }

    #[test_case("a/8/8/8/8/8/8/8"; "for invalid letter code at start")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/c/8/8/8/8"; "for invalid letter code in middle")]
    #[test_case("0/8/8/8/8/8/8/8"; "for invalid digit code at start")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/9/8/8/8/8"; "for invalid digit code in middle")]
    fn it_returns_invalid_code_in_rank(placement_substring: &str) {
        let res = Fen::validate_piece_placement_substring(placement_substring);

        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::InvalidCodeInRank(_, ..)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }

    #[test_case("8/8/245/8/8/8/8/8"; "for rank too large due to empties")]
    #[test_case("ppppppppp/8/8/8/8/8/8/8"; "for rank too large due to pieces")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/8/2pp2pp2/8/8/8"; "for rank too large due to pieces and empties")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/8/ppp/8/8/8"; "for rank too small pieces only")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/8/2/8/8/8"; "for rank too small empties only")]
    #[test_case("8/8/8/8/2p2/8/8/8"; "for rank too small empties and pieces")]
    fn it_returns_incorrect_rank_size(placement_substring: &str) {
        let res = Fen::validate_piece_placement_substring(placement_substring);

        match res {
            Ok(_) => assert!(false, "Error not returned"),
            Err(FenValidationError::IncorrectRankSize(_, ..)) => assert!(true),
            Err(_) => assert!(false, "Wrong error type returned")
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: This looks pretty good. I'd only move the import up to the top of the unit file and add a `impl TryFrom<[&str; 6]> for Fen` that I'd defer to in `impl TryFrom<&str> for Fen {` after having checked the split string's length.

Comment: @RichardNeumann - Thanks, could you please elaborate on that in an answer?